# how to submit targets via the nessus API?

Tags: nessus

I am trying to create a new scan in Nessus (6.4) via the API following the documentation. I have a policy set up and the code to create the scan is

```
import requests

headers = {
    "X-ApiKeys": "accessKey = 8cc43676fe7e9046353fcd36c41c61f4f78f7a8df646653fbde4641e352d36d9; secretKey = ab7eeafbe3f9f544b10496ff63297f8f55692cc5f4dca3f3d74e0917b6ec2ed0;"
}

data = {
    "uuid": "ab4bacd2-05f6-425c-9d79-3ba3940ad1c24e51e1f403febe40",
    "settings": {
        "name": "myscan1",
        "policy_id": "4",
        "enabled": "false",
        "text_targets": "192.168.1.1"
    }
}
r = requests.post('https://localhost:8834/scans', data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code, r.text)
```

This outputs

```
(400, u'{"error":"Invalid \'targets\' field"}')
```

The documentation explicitly gives an example for the POST body:

> Below is a sample body for this request:
>
> ```
> {
>     "uuid": {template_uuid},
>     "settings": {
>         "name": {string},
>         "description": {string},
>         "emails": {string},
>         "enabled": "true",
>         "launch": {string},
>         "folder_id": {integer},
>         "policy_id": {integer},
>         "scanner_id": {integer},
>         "text_targets": {string},
>         "use_dashboard": {boolean}
>     }
> }
> ```

I checked an actual scan creation in the interface, analyzing the HTTPS traffic. The POST body starts with

```
{  
   "uuid":"ad629e16-03b6-8c1d-cef6-ef8c9dd3c658d24bd260ef5f9e66",
   "settings":{  
      "name":"test1",
      "description":"",
      "folder_id":"3",
      "scanner_id":"1",
      "text_targets":"192.168.1.1",
      "file_targets":"",
(...)
```

so it looks like the targets are provided correctly.

Any idea what else to check regarding the `targets` field??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to `json.dumps()` the `POST` payload (and possibly add a `content-type` to the header).

The example below works (this time the authentication is done via a token from `/session`, but the same works with the authorization keys in the question)

```
headers = {
    "X-Cookie": "token={token};".format(token=token),
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "uuid": "ab4bacd2-05f6-425c-9d79-3ba3940ad1c24e51e1f403febe40",
    "settings": {
        "name": "myscan1",
        "policy_id": "4",
        "enabled": "false",
        "text_targets": "192.168.1.1",
    }
}

r = requests.post('https://localhost:8834/scans', data=json.dumps(data), verify=False, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hey there @Woj

maybe you could help answer my very similiar question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675898/nessus-restful-api-java-problems-implementing-post

thank you

Comment: I had a different problem while passing payload to the data. `"content-type": "application/json"` and `data=json.dumps(data)` fixed it - Thanks! :D